# How can you make a loop so that you are creating this same graph over and over but for a different variable each time?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

This is the coding that I have right now that creates the graph that I want. This is only for well 'aa1' though, and I want to learn how to make a loop so that I can make this graph for all of my wells. Any ideas?

```
longer_raindata %>% 
  select(well, metal, level, smpl_mth) %>% 
  filter(well == 'aa1') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(metal, level, fill = smpl_mth))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('plum', 'lightsteelblue', 'darkolivegreen', 'indianred'))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  labs(title = 'Metals in Well AA1',
       x = 'Metals',
       y = 'µg/l')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you mind providing [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.  To post your data type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do e.g. `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 10))` for the first 10 rows of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to put your code into a plotting function which takes one argument `.well` and adjust your filter statement to filter your data for that `.well`.

Then you could use e.g. `lapply` to loop over the `unique` wells in your dataset to get a list of plots for each well.

Using some fake example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

longer_raindata <- data.frame(
  metal = LETTERS[1:3],
  level = 1:6,
  well = rep(c("aa1", "aa2"), each = 6),
  smpl_mth = rep(letters[1:2], each = 3)
)

plot_fun <- function(.well) {
  longer_raindata %>% 
    select(well, metal, level, smpl_mth) %>% 
    filter(well == .well) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(metal, level, fill = smpl_mth))+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('plum', 'lightsteelblue', 'darkolivegreen', 'indianred'))+
    geom_col(position = "dodge")+
    labs(title = paste0('Metals in Well ', toupper(.well)),
         x = 'Metals',
         y = 'µg/l')  
}

lapply(unique(longer_raindata$well), plot_fun)
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]